# Add constraint to Postgres Table based on value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgres Table

```
column_a | column_b  | 
---------+-----------+
 001     | 1         | 
 004     | 2         | 
 006     | 3         | 
 007     | 4         | 
 008     | 5         | 
 104     | 0         | 
 204     | 0         |
```

I want to add a constraint to this table such that whenever `(RIGHT(column_a, 1) = '4' OR column_a = '006') AND column_a <> '004'` the value of `column_b` needs to be equal to 0. If that's not the case, I want to throw an error.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So `006     | 3` is an error?

Comment: You should explain your constraint. Because your OR AND are contradictory

Comment: Yes `006 | 3` is an error. Basically I want all values of `column_b` to be 0 when the right-most digit of `column_a` is 0. The exceptions to this are when `column_a = '004'` then it does not have to be the case that `column_b` is 0. Also when `column_a = '006'` then I need it to be 0

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have the answer already you just need to rearrange your logic to an expression that you can throw in a CHECK constraint.

You have a statement of the form `P -> Q` where `->` is logical implication. But from elementary logic we know that:

```
(P -> Q) <-> (-P | Q)
```

Applying that to your implication and translating to SQL we get the SQL expression:

```
NOT ((RIGHT(column_a, 1) = '4' OR column_a = '006') AND column_a <> '004') OR (column_b = 0)
```

Then wrap it up in a CHECK:

```
alter table your_table
add constraint whatever_you_want_to_call_it
check (
    not ((right(column_a, 1) = '4' or column_a = '006') and column_a <> '004')
    or (column_b = 0)
)
```

You could use De Morgan's laws to move the `not` inside first parenthesized expression if you wanted or you could leave it outside to highlight the `-P | Q` pattern so that people would (maybe, hopefully, ...) recognize the implication in disguise.